# Open the url in the next page by adding the text of input field in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, input, react-state

My Method:

```
launchSearch() {
 let searchString = this.searchRef.current?.value;
        window.open(
      "https://sample.com/list/market/" + searchString,
      "api-explorer"
    );
  }
```

Inside render Method:

```
<TextInput
        placeholder="Placeholder text"
        onKeyPress={(event) => {
          if (event.key === "Enter") {
            this.launchSearch();
          }
        }}
        ref = {this.searchRef}
      />
```

I am able to pass the **ref** from the textinput to my launchSearch Method, and able to open the URL in new tab by concating the searchRef in URL. Is there any other way to doing this, without using ref? Using State and "value" in textInput. I am trying using the state by passing **value  = {this.state.search}** and in launchSearch:

```
launchSearch() {
        window.open(
      "https://sample.com/list/market/" + this.state.search,
      "api-explorer"
    );
  }
```

It is opening the new window, but not accepting the search value I've entered. Can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use onKeyDown

```
  <TextInput
    placeholder="Placeholder text"
    onKeyDown={(event) => {
      if (event.key === "Enter") {
        this.launchSearch(event.target.value);
      }
    }}
  />

  launchSearch(search) {
      window.open("https://sample.com/list/market/"+search, "api-explorer");
  }
```

Comment: passing event.target.value works without using ref. Thanks

Comment: I wonder how can i delete this text in the input. because when i m writing onChange = {()=> {this.deleteText(event.target.value)}}. Its giving me an error, that object is possibly null. I have made a button and on click of that button i want to clear the text of this<TextInput>. A bit help would be appreciated